# The most basic HttpGet request on Java

Tags: java, json, http

I need help performing a RESTful call to a website that returns a JSON object. I'm stuck with the options that are available but I would prefer to use something that comes right out of the box and not install any third party plugins.

Here's what I currently have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40apple");

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
```

I know that the URL used in this example returns the following:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}
```

Which is fine by me, I just want to at least convert the JSON response into a string so that I can move on from here. I'm very familiar to how REST works and it's been pretty easy to get it working on Objective-C and Python but Java for some reason has a dozen implementations for getting it to work properly, I'm just looking for the most basic approach possible, I'm not doing anything crazy like uploading images to a server.

So the issue with my code above is that I'm getting a `ClientProtocolException` error and the `httpClient.execute()` requires a try catch statement, this is something brand new to me, I've never had a compiler yell at me for not inserting try catch statements.

How can I fix this to call a url that converts a very basic JSON object to a string?

Comment: Start by having a look at [Catching and Handling Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) and there are a number of JSON libraries available for Java, I believe that the [Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library is relativly popular...

Comment: Use Simple JSON parser https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: Please explain how a very basic JSON object **is not** a `String`?

Comment: ummm... well a basic JSON from twitter needs to make it to the client first before actually becoming a string.

Comment: *Why* are you not wanting to use a library? Is this just for personal education, or is this code to solve some problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
try {
        HttpResponse response;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getConnection = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(getConnection);
            String JSONString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),
                    "UTF-8");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString); //Assuming it's a JSON Object

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```